# iPhone add to home screen blank page

Tags: reactjs

I write a website with `react js`. when my in my iPhone safari type my IP computer  then `add to home screen` have blank page with my background.
manifest.json :

```
  "short_name": "may app name",
  "name": "my app name",
  "gcm_sender_id": "--------",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon_IranTracking.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "iOS 192_Trans_True.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "iOS 512_Trans_True.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display":"fullscreen"
}
```

and this screenshot of my app
this screen run in safari:
[image]

and this is the screenshot after `add to home screen` :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change manifest.json file. and work fine!
"start_url": "./index.html" to "start_url": ".",